# matlab slice 3d matrix according to another matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

Suppose that:

```
A=randi(5,4,3,2)
B=reshape([1,2,3;3,2,3],1,3,2)
```

The first dimension of B represents the index of the desired element in that dimension of A. So that means I want get following elements: A( 1,1,1),A( 2,2,1),A( 3,3,1),A( 3,1,2),A( 2,2,2),A( 3,3,2); Could you please help me get this in an efficient way? Thanks.

Comment: what do you do with A's 4th dimension? have all it's elements? The example you gave for B doesnt make sense to me because it just reads: `B(:,:,1)= 1     3     2` , `B(:,:,2) =    2     3     3`

Comment: Thanks. I have got answer from this post: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/360788-how-to-slice-2d-matrix-based-on-a-vector-of-indices-of-each-row